# Syntax for GenerHibernateDAO likes

Tags: java, hibernate

How can i use GenericHibernateDao to get a query like below?

SELECT * FROM TEAM WHERE name likes "%teamName%"

I had something like

```
Team currentTeam = m_teamDao.findByAttribute("name", teamName);
```

which is working like

```
SELECT * FROM TEAM WHERE name =teamName
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use **Criteria Queries**. Refer the following code snippet

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Team.class).add(Restrictions.like("name","%teamName%"));
```